# Angular assets loading optimization

Tags: angular, optimization, assets

We have a huge huge angular application consisting over 9 different modules. Each of these modules are an independent angular application, served on an Nginx server.
By opening each of these modules, assets and fonts that are needed for the application get loaded, which makes the loading time long.
Is there a way to load all the assets once and cache them in the browser?

Comment: Well, caching is not really a task on the side of angular, but rather a task on server side (nginx). You should probably take a look at caching for nginx and at least add some "nginx" tag, so that the experts can help out here :)

Comment: great, thanks for the tip Fabian